# Performance Issue on Laravel 9 Application Using TALL Stack (not in Docker or WSL)

Tags: php, laravel, performance, laravel-livewire

I am facing serious performance issues on my Laravel 9 and 10 applications. I'm using a TALL stack (Tailwind, Alpine, Livewire, Laravel), and I've noticed significant lag when loading my assets, which I'm struggling to explain.

Specifically, each of my JS and CSS files take approximately 2 seconds to load if I keep them in the 'vendor' directory. However, if I manually move these files to the 'public' directory, the load times improve significantly.

This issue occurs both in my development environment (PHP FPM 8.1.2, Nginx, Valet Linux, Ubuntu 22.04 (not in a VM), Intel Core i5, 16Go RAM, SSD M.2 NVMe) and in production (PHP FPM 8.2, Apache, Debian 11) even after cache:view, cache:config, etc.

As a temporary solution, I've moved the files to the public folder, but the application itself (excluding assets) also takes about 2 seconds to load. This makes it challenging to make it responsive with Livewire without experiencing form refresh delays of around 2 seconds each.

Loading from "vendor" directory :

```
/admin/oncalls           ████████████████████████████ 1.54s
/livewire/livewire.js                                ██████████████████████████████ 1.54s
/filament/assets/app.js                              █████████████████████████████ 1.37s
/filament/assets/echo.js                             ███████████████████████████████████████████████ 2.32s
```

Loading from "public" directory :

```
/admin/oncalls           ████████████████████████████ 1.54s
/livewire/livewire.js                                █ 9ms
/filament/assets/app.js                              █ 6ms
/filament/assets/echo.js                             █ 6ms
```

[image: Loading from "vendor" directory]

The application loading time issue doesn't seem to be related to database queries since the Laravel Debugbar shows rapid queries.
[image: Debugbar]

Memory usage seems quite high however. Don't know how to find out why is that so high.

Access right do not seems to be the problem either

```
drwxrwxr-x  81 david david   4096 mai   17 10:30 vendor
drwxrwxr-x   5 david david   4096 mai   25 13:44 public
```

I've been looking for a solution for several months now but to no avail.

In order to bring more details, I add this xdebug profiling displayed from Clockwork :

[image]

Its truncated because the time consumming part is displayed on top but if the rest of the list is necessary to understand the problem I will add it.

I looked into the vendor dir to find where is uasort() called and commented it in /vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/SortableIterator.php in the method getIterator() at line 105 and the loading time dropped from 2.36s to 0.935s.
The backtrace shows that it is Filament that calls it indirectly :

```
vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/SortableIterator.php:116
Composer\Autoload\includeFile

Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader:428
loadClass

Symfony/Component/Finder/Finder:454
sortByName

Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem:599
allFiles

Filament/FilamentServiceProvider:152
registerComponents
```

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes the perfomance graphics I just posted is a ASCII representation of the developer tools because Stack Overflow won't let me post screenshots. When its on my development environment its not cached but on my production environment it is. But the result is the same. The same files are still slow.
Edit: It seems that Stack Overflow let me post pictures now

Comment: Those are some very long waiting times. Do the same files show the same difference if you load them individually in your browser? Just put the file paths in the address bar of your browser, one by one, and see the result in the network tab. Doing this exclude every other possible problem except for the way your server is serving the files.

Comment: Indeed. And yes it takes approximately the same amount of time individually: 1.34s instead of 1.54s

Comment: Sorry, your feedback isn't very useful/precise, I don't think I can help.

Comment: Sorry, what information would you like to know ? I tried to post all I could to be precise but I don't know what I could add

Comment: Well, I wanted to know something like this: *"Loading directly from the vendor directory, url 'https://?????/filament/assets/echo.js', uncached takes 1.53 s, and cached 1.33 s. Same file from the public directory, url 'https://????/????/echo.js' takes 9 ms whether it is cached or uncached."*. Precise and comprehensive. Then I would have asked you to place a simple text file in the vendor directory, and if that is still slow, and not when placed in the public directory, we would have learned something.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry don't take it for ill will.
Since I'm on my development environ to make tests, I work uncached.

Loading directly from the vendor directory, url 'https://laravel10.test/livewire/livewire.js' = 1.34s,
Same file from the public directory, url 'https://laravel10.test/vendor/livewire/livewire.js' = 8ms",

Then I tried to put test.js file in /vendor/livewire/livewire/dist/test.js of 471B (next to livewire.js) but it wasn't accessible from there : error 404
The same file from /public/vendor/livewire/test.js loaded in 4ms.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Wait, I am very confused now, when you say `vendor`, you are not refering to the `PROJECT_ROOT/vendor` PHP folder, right?

Comment: I am. But using Laravel, if you want to override assets located in PROJECT_ROOT/vendor you need to put it in a PROJECT_ROOT/public/vendor directory then it displays as domain.com/vendor/livewire/livewire.js instead of domain_name.com/livewire/livewire.js

Comment: Is this a fresh project or have there been modifications? If not fresh, when did it start being slow? _"Laravel 9 and 10 applications"_ It happens on multiple applications? _"This issue occurs both in my development environment and in production"_ Are all users being affected or only you?

Comment: When I figured that I couldn't find where the problem came from I made a brand new project using Laravel 10 (the real project is on Laravel 9) and find out that the slowing down was when I started to install the Filament backoffice admin panel but I'm confused since the Filament Demo App (available from their github) run smoothly on my machine.
Yes every user is concerned by this problem.

Comment: Your vendor directory should *never* be accessible to the browser, nor are the scripts there necessarily intended for direct usage. There's a reason the "public" folder is called "public".

Comment: @hunterd From your profiler I can see that BladeIconsServiceProvider is quite slow. From the package they say _"When working with Blade Icons, and third party icon sets in particularly, you'll often be working with large icon sets. This can slow down your app tremendously"_ Can you try `php artisan icons:cache` ? https://github.com/blade-ui-kit/blade-icons#caching

Comment: You are totally right. Thank you so much. Didn't know about the icons:cache command.
It even dropped the /vendor assets access speed. Now livewire.js load in 86ms from the vendor directory. It is still slower than the 12ms loading from /public/vendor though but still much faster too.

Comment: @ceejayoz the assets from Livewire are automatically published I guess since it is how it work out of the box. I think it is not accessible directly from vendor since when I tried to put test.js next to livewire.js in the PROJECT_ROOT/vendor it wasn't available publicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php artisan icons:cache
```

solved the problem. Thank you Clément Baconnier for the solution.